# How to take sample form two different vectors?

Tags: r, sample, sampling

I have a two vectors of different sizes. say

```
x <- rnorm(50, 2, 0.8) 
y <- rnorm(35, 4, 0.5)
```

I want to create new vector `z`of size 100 which contains sample of size 75 observation from `x` and sample of size 25 from `y`.

I thinking to use `sample()` function of base package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- rnorm(50, 2, 0.8)
y <- rnorm(35, 4, 0.5)
z<-c(sample(x = x,size = 75,replace = T),sample(x = y,size = 25,replace = T))
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working for me.